# Does Quantum Key Distribution (QKD) guarantee perfect secrecy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Following the book: Quantum Communication, Quantum Networks, and Quantum Sensing- Ivan Djordjevic.

A perfectly secret cryptosystem is one for which the uncertainty (or Shannon entropy) of the key (K) is always greater or equal to the uncertainty of the message (M):
$$H(M)\leq H(K)$$
In some paragraphs below (page 218), the author states that "The security of QKD is guaranteed by the laws of quantum mechanics".
I want to know which of the following interpretations is correct:

1. Due (for instance) to the no-cloning theorem or the indistinguishability of nonorthogonal states, the actions of an eavesdropper are restricted, and therefore QKD is secure in this sense.
2. Using QKD (For instance BB84 protocol) the last inequality is always guaranteed (Which would be a stronger result).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In quantum key distribution there is no message in the ordinary sense of the word. That is, no information is conveyed from A to B. Rather, it is a method whereby a random classical bitstring can be made to appear at both A and B, without it appearing anywhere else. To be precise, bounds can be set on the probability that the bitstring or parts of it have been duplicated elsewhere.

Once the parties have this shared random bitstring they would use it as a key to launch some key-based cryptographic protocol. If they want ultimate security they would use it as a one-time pad.

QKD enables the parties to establish various bounds on what an evesdropper might have done while the key was being established, and they are strong bounds in the limit of large numbers of bits.

However, all protocols, including QKD, can in principle be compromised by issues such as human error and technological faults. There is no ultimate guarantee against those. A technological fault could be, for example, a notionally single-photon source that actually produced pairs of photons, or a measuring device at A or B which emitted some faint classical signal to the evesdropper. The idea is that as long as A and B have complete control over their own equipment and immediate surroundings, and do not make mistakes, then they can guarantee some upper bound on the information that third parties (evesdroppers) could have about the key that becomes established between them.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification.